# How do I make a certain section of code run for every x number of lines of data?

Tags: python, for-loop, enumerate

I want the code below to be applied to every 130 lines of data. Currently, when I run it the code only applied to the first 130 lines but I want a way to make it cycle through every 130 lines of my data. Alternatively, maybe I could split the data in some way so that after the for loop the computer doesn't just reach the end of the file and stop?

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as dataset:
    for line in dataset:
        if 'CAFE' in line:
             for i, lt in enumerate(dataset):
                 if i > 1 and i < 130 and i %2 == 0:
                       lt_1 = int(lt, 16)
                       lt_2 = float(str(lt_1))
                       print(lt_2)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the last sentence. What should happen when the file has been completely read? Is this relevant to the title of your question?

Comment: Did the indenting get messed up when you pasted the code?  Or is that really how it looks?  This is Python; it matters.

Comment: What part of the "code below" do you want to run on each group of 130 lines of data? What should happen if the number of lines in the file isn't an exact multiple of 130?

Comment: Martineau, I would like to run the entire code (starting with for line in dataset) on every 130 lines. The code should stop, however, when it is less than 130 lines remaining.